# PHP: Relationship between __isset() and __get()

Tags: php, magic-methods

I recently had a short discussion with another developer about the relationship between PHP's `__isset()` and `__get()` magic methods.  It was brought about by a class that we have which lazy-loads other objects via the `__get()` method (lazy-loading meaning that the property doesn't exist until first accessed, at which point the object is instantiated and returned).  We had differing opinions on what `__isset()` should return for a property that has yet to be loaded, though.  The property technically doesn't exist (it isn't *set*, or at the very least, it's set but currently `NULL`), but a call to it will also technically succeed (barring any exceptions) and return a non-`NULL` value.

So, my question is, in this situation should `__isset()` simply be an indicator of whether or not `__get()` will succeed for the same argument (return `TRUE` if `__get()` will succeed and return a non-`NULL` value).  Or, should it behave more technically, and return `FALSE`, since the data does not yet exist (even though it *will* when first accessed)?

A simple example:

```
class Foo {
    protected $data;

    public function __get($prop) {
        if ($prop == 'bar') {
            $this->data['bar'] = new Bar;
            return $this->data['bar'];
        }
    }

    public function __isset($prop) {
        if ($prop == 'bar') {
            // What goes here?
            // return isset($this->data[$prop]) would mean
            // that the first call to isset($foo->bar) below will be FALSE
            // which means that using logic like this would always fail
            // and __get() would never be called:
            // isset($foo->bar) ? $foo->bar->baz : 'foo->bar not set'
        }
    }
}

class Bar {}

$foo = new Foo;
var_dump(isset($foo->bar)); // ???
$bar = $foo->bar;
var_dump(isset($foo->bar)); // bool(true)
```

Comment: `__isset` should check the value that's returned by `__get` to see if it's set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to consider this from the perspective of a *user* of the class. Assume that `$foo` is of `class Foo`, and you have this code:

```
if(isset($foo->bar)) {
    var_dump($foo->bar); // #1
}
else {
    // $foo->bar is "not set", right?
    $x = $foo->bar;
    var_dump($x); // #2
}
```

Rhetorical questions: would you expect #1 to ever print `null`? Would you expect #2 to print anything *except* `null`?

Of course not. If it worked like that, then users of `class Foo` would spend most of their working day cursing the author.

Assuming that I have convinced you, it's quite simple to start from the desired behavior and work back to how it should be achieved, namely to implement `__isset` like this:

```
public function __isset($prop) {
    $val = $this->$prop;
    return isset($val);
}
```

Comment: +1 good sample function illustrating what the end user is likely checking.

Comment: This is what I'm leaning towards, except for the quirky nature of `isset()` with respect to `NULL` values.  For example, if class `Foo` has property `public $foo = NULL;` - what's expected when you do something like `isset($foo->foo)`?  The property *exists*, but it has no value, so common expectations from most PHP developers familiar with how `isset()` works would be that it should be `FALSE`, since it has no value.  In the same manner, if `$foo` is lazy-loaded, we know that the property *exists*, but it also has no value yet.  Therein lies my confusion on what it should return.

Comment: @drrcknlsn: Actually, whether the property *exists* is not relevant and is probably just confusing you. Since `isset` returns `false` for a `null` value that may very well "exist", we have to follow suit whether we like it or not. If `null` is a legal value for the property and thus unsuitable to use as a guard, just add another property e.g. `private $gotFoo = false;` to mark whether you have actually performed the lazy loading already.

Comment: On second thought, I guess maybe the fact that the property is lazy-loaded should be an encapsulated implementation detail that isn't revealed to the outside world.  Thus, calling code should not be aware that certain properties are lazy-loaded, and would have no reason to suspect as much.  Okay, you have me convinced.  :-)

Comment: @drrcknlsn: Yes, leaking the "virtual" nature of properties to callers is only asking for trouble. But you may want to tell them that it's lazy-loaded so that they understand the performance implications.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what an `isset()` check means to your code. What does the code using `isset()` actually care about?

Is it just asking of the property is value (as in, can be accessed)? Then check to see if the value can be accessed through `__get()` and return the result.

Is it asking if the property is valid and not `null`? Then actually load the value and return the result.

Is it asking if the value has been loaded? Then check if `__get()` has been called, and return the result.

But it should reflect the use of your class, not some arbitrary rule.

Comment: The use would depend on the calling code, which I have no control over or insight into as this is a library class.  In essence, I'm trying to create the behavior that would be *most expected* by other developers, if that makes sense.

Comment: @drrcknlsn I still think it makes sense to consider the use. An ActiveRecord class has different considerations than a API wrapper.

Comment: @drrcknlsn And since it's a library, the most important part is *document* what `isset()` means. Does it check if the value has be *loaded*? If the value has been *set* (regardless of setting it to `null`)? Or if the property is a *valid* property?